# ASP.net SQL data reader to WebLink to XML

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, xml

I'm trying to pull some info from SQL to put inside a weblink i've had some help getting the code together however something is wrong.

The way this works is;

SQLDB, Get 2 values > put 2 values into a URL > Read the XML that the URL gives me > put into a text box.

Here is my current chunk of code im having trouble with;

```
SqlConnection conn = null;

try
{
    string sql = "SELECT ApiKey, VeriF FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @username";

    conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["READER"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

    SqlParameter UserN = new SqlParameter();
    UserN.ParameterName = "@username";
    UserN.Value = User.Identity.Name;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(UserN);

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    string url;

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        url = string.Format(
            "https://api.eveonline.com/account/Characters.xml.aspx?keyID={0}&&vCODE={1}",
            reader.GetString(0),
            reader.GetString(1));

        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(url);
        XmlNodeList ndlist = xdoc.SelectNodes("/eveapi/result/rowset/row");
        foreach(XmlNode xmlnode in ndlist)
        {                        
                ename.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["Name"].InnerText;
        }                

    }

    else
    {
        url = null; // username not found                     
    }

}
finally
{
    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Close();
}
```

The values it should be pulling from SQL is:

```
Apikey = 4602486
VeriF = BHGVeXQkRLKLkIkZQHdeyUxmUz9EfUwbvGzoc2eO4ZR8kRMYxk8PbD4LMwLF7BvH
```

and the final link should be this:

```
https://api.eveonline.com/account/Characters.xml.aspx?keyID=4602486&&vCODE=BHGVeXQkRLKLkIkZQHdeyUxmUz9EfUwbvGzoc2eO4ZR8kRMYxk8PbD4LMwLF7BvH
```

im getting an error at this part:

```
Line 52:                 if (reader.HasRows)
```

Description of error is:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Here is my edited code; however im still having the same problem :@

```
 private void SQLC()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;

        try
        {
            string URL;
            string sql = "SELECT ApiKey, VeriF FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @username";

            conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["READER"].ConnectionString);

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            SqlParameter UserN = new SqlParameter();
            UserN.ParameterName = "@username";
            UserN.Value = User.Identity.Name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(UserN);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    URL = string.Format(
                   "https://api.eveonline.com/char/AccountBalance.xml.aspx?keyID={0}&&vCODE={1}",
                     dr.GetString(0),
                     dr.GetString(1));


                    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xdoc.Load(URL);
                    XmlNodeList ndlist = xdoc.SelectNodes("/eveapi/result/key/rowset/row");
                    foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in ndlist)
                    {
                        iskammount.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["characterName"].InnerText;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                URL = iskammount.Text = "Error";
            } 
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

with a new error:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
```

Comment: `reader` is probably null. check to see if `cmd.ExecuteReader()` is returning back any results

Comment: I'm guessing so.. however im having a hard time trying to debug that bit.

Comment: The content of your error description points to a web request. I do not think, that `reader.HasRows` is the real point of the problem. Try to set a stop mark and go through your code step by step. Check the content of "url", try to call it "classically"... Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: One more hint: "review the stack trace" is a good advise... Try to find out who called the error producing command. Open the Exception-Viewer and look into the "InnerException" too...

Comment: new update; Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'. is the error im getting now.. will it have any affect if in my DB one column is Int and the other is Nvarchar?

Comment: yes i got it :D seems i just needed to tweek this line; dr.GetSqlInt32(0),
                         dr.GetString(1));